# How to get an array of a property on an object in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, key-value-coding

I have an array of Tag objects that have a property called tag, which is a string.

```
public struct Tag {
    public let name: String
}
```

I would like to get an array of all of these name properties.

Given an array of tags, in Objective-C I would accomplish this with this line:

```
NSArray *tagNames = [tags valueForKey:@"name"]
```

How can I achieve the same thing in Swift?

I've tried:

```
let tagNames = tags.map({ $0.name })
```

But get a compiler error: "Value of type '[Tag]' has no member 'name'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have an array which contains another array of Tag objects.
This works for me:

```
let tags = [Tag(name: "tag1"), Tag(name: "tag2"), Tag(name: "tag3")]
let names = tags.map{$0.name }
print("Names: \(names)")
```

Comment: Yeah it's working now I've gone back to it. I must have initialised the array incorrectly or something.